# Blazor Horizontal Scrollbar Issue

Tags: css, header, blazor, resize, sidebar

I am developing an application in Microsoft Blazor and I have a problem with the UI when I am resizing the window.

Normally if the content fits into the window, there is no blank space on the topbar/header:
[image]

But when I am shrinking the window and scrolling to the right side, there is blank space:
[image]

Seems that even the content of the container "content" is large, header is not stretching...

Here is my MainLayout:

```
<div class="page">
   <Sidebar />

    <div class="main">
        <Header />

        <article class="content px-4">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>Please sign in to use the Platform...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorized>
                   @Body
                </Authorized>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </article>

    </div>
```

Here is the css of the Page:

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the css of the Main:

```
.main {
    flex: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is the css od the Sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
}

.sidebar_clp { //Colapsed State
    width: 110px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar_exp { //Expanded State
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is the css of the Header:

```
.top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    height: 3.5rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the css of the Content:

```
.content {
    padding-top: 1.1rem;
    flex: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Any ideas how can this be fixed?

Comment: justify-content: flex-end;?

Comment: justify-content: flex-end; forces the content to be on the end (right), if i remove it the issue remains and the content is on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of trials, I ended up with this setting:

```
.top-row {
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

The lines that are making the difference are:

```
    position: absolute;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
```